# I want to retrieve New_amt field from following document using c#

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, collections, document

I want to retrieve `New_amt` field from following document using `C#` :

```
> db.Customer.find().pretty()


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6daad5fc5bef1b941bec3c"),
    "Customer_Id" : "1",
    "Name" : "aaaaa",
    "Address" : "lalalal",
    "PhoneNo" : "7878787",
    "OptionalNo" : "7878787",
    "Date" : ISODate("2019-02-20T19:30:29.095Z"),
    "Installment" : [
                      {
                        "id" : ObjectId("5c6dab0bfc5bef1b941bec3f"),
                        "New_amt" : "0",
                        "Net_amt" : "6000",
                        "Paid" : "200",
                        "Remains" : "5800",
                        "Date" : ISODate("2019-02-20T19:31:23.772Z")
                      }
                   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need MongoDriver to c#, one time you have that

instance it

```
        var _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var _database = _client.GetDatabase("YOUR DATABASE");
        var _bitCollection = _database.GetCollection<MODEL>("YOUR COLLECTION");
```

one time you have that you can filter it

```
        var filter = Builders<MODEL>.Filter.Eq(fieldName, fieldValue);
        var result = await _bitCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

and result return a List, if don't have model you can use
dynamic as model, but it have some many problems sometimes